# What does it mean when you get a compile error "looks like a function definition" for a class declaration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I recently encountered this problem. I found many instances of people asking the question—[here, for example](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=982326)—but no concrete answers.

Here's the sample code hoisted from that link:

```
class AFX_BASE_APPLICATION_APP_CLASS CFileExtension 
{
public:
   CFileExtension ();           
   virtual ~CFileExtension ();
};
```

The error this generates is:

`c:\FileExtension.h(14) : error C2470: 'CFileExtension' : looks like a function definition, but there is no formal parameter list; skipping apparent body`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You've almost certainly missed the header which defines `AFX_BASE_APPLICATION_APP_CLASS`. In that case, it would be passed through unaltered and VC++ would assume that `CFileExtension` was a function that returned `class AFX_BASE_APPLICATION_APP_CLASS`.

And, since it thinks it's a function, it also thinks it needs parentheses.

You just need to find where `AFX_BASE_APPLICATION_APP_CLASS` is defined and `#include` that file.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same compiler error. The problem was a **missing colon**

My code was something like:

```
int MyClass:doSomething() {

}
```

It should have been: (Note '::' instead of ':'

```
int MyClass::doSomething() {

}
```

Comment: This was my problem too - in VS2010 "mixed mode", where there's no intellisense to help you!

Answer (score 3):

...and the answer, since I couldn't be bothered to make a login for any of those forums, but I already had an OpenID :-)

In my case (and likely all the ones I found), the problem was that I was missing an #include for the header file that contained the definition for the macro preceding the class name. The macro is most likely used as a build-configuration switched way to turn on __declspec(dllexport).

The way I discovered this was by going into the project properties, "C/C++" | Preprocessor and turning on "Generate Preprocessed File." When I looked at the preprocessed output, I discovered that the macro was included verbatim instead of being expanded.

Comment: Tim is correct, I was just faced with this error and I had missed a preprocessor define that would have defined the macro preceding the class name. Once the macro is defined the error is resolved...
To be frank, I was going to just up vote Tim's answer, but found out my Rep score was not high enough :-) EB

Answer (score 3):

just define `AFX_BASE_APPLICATION_APP_CLASS`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is using a __declspec(dllimport) instead of __declspec(dllexport) or no declspec at all as a class / function prefix in Visual C++.

If you mix this up, your class may also fail to get recognized as such and you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions worked. The problem as posted in OP was coming from including the class:

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CMyClass : public CObject
{
public  :
// ....
}
```

This was an export class from a dll which I want to use in a console exe. If I create the console application as 'using mfc' in the create wizard, then this 
error was not happening but that option results in creating a different structure of the app.

Anyways I tried to include various headers so it knows `AFX_EXT_CLASS`, defined it but nothing worked. Long story short, the solution is that we have to enable to use MFC for the application for it to understand the MFC exported class from the dll. How we do it is by editing `.vcproj` file and insert the line `UseOfMFC="2"` as shown below:

```
<Configurations>
    <Configuration
        Name="Debug|Win32"
        OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
        IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
        ConfigurationType="1"
        UseOfMFC="2" <-------------Insert this line here
        CharacterSet="1"
```

Also `#include <afx.h>` to stdafx.h ( I included it at top right before the first include).

Now relead, clean and build the error should go away.

There was no other way to change this option from project settings. This option is different from <kbd>Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> General >> 'Use of MFC'</kbd>.

**Update**

The `UseOfMFC="2"` trick maybe useful elsewhere but apparently if you just `#include <afx.h>` AND change the settings  `project properties >> General >> 'Use of MFC'` to Use MFC in shared dll, than this error goes away. If you don't change the later settings a compiler error will occur

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

Changing this actually also does set `UseOfMFC="2"`in the project file, so this is the right way.