# class exporting error (error C2470: looks like a function definition)

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2005

I can't export a class:

```
#ifndef SDBIDI
#define SDBIDI
#ifndef SDBIDI_FLAG
#define SDBIDI_ORIENT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define SDBIDI_ORIENT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#include "TCInfoSuVars.h" //class is here!

SDBIDI_ORIENT int myFoo(FILE *file); // exporting function

#endif
```

**class definition in TCInfoSuVars.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <hash_map>

class SDBIDI_ORIENT TCInfoSuVars
{
public:
    std::string id;
    std::string tcVal;

    TCInfoSuVars();
    TCInfoSuVars(std::string _tcVal, std::string _id);

    ~TCInfoSuVars();
};
```

Getting a error:

**myProgram.cpp**

```
#define SDBIDI_FLAG
```

**output:**

```
TCInfoSuVars.h(14) : error C2470: 'TCInfoSuVars' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

And if I write

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TCInfoSuVars
```

everything works OK.

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, your `TCInfoSuVars.h` header depends on macro definitions made in that other header with `SDBIDI_ORIENT` in it (you didn't provide a name). Why in this case are you including `TCInfoSuVars.h` into that other header instead of doing it the other way around???

Comment: @AndreyT because some functions in unnamed ".h" use this class

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean when you get a compile error "looks like a function definition" for a class declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684715/what-does-it-mean-when-you-get-a-compile-error-looks-like-a-function-definition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somewhere you're including `TCInfoSuVars.h` **before** `SDBIDI_ORIENT` is defined - Make sure you include the header file that defines `SDBIDI_ORIENT` first.

Comment: it was like that before.. Could it be precompiled headers? How to recompile header files? thanks (Visual Studio 2005)

Comment: You don't compile header files, you compile cpp files which include headers. Do a full rebuild of the project if you want to ensure precompiled headers are up to date. But, the answer still explains what happens.